# How can I add text to my hexagonal elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a grid of hexagons and I need some text on top of these hexagons. I have tried different things but nothing has worked.

I also tried to place a background-image on top of it (with the number), but I also can't get the image on it.

**HTML/CSS**

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px; 
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-left: 30%;
}
ol.even {
  position: relative;
  left: 3.63em;
}
ol.odd {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -6.5%;
  margin-bottom: -6.5%;
}
.hex {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 4em; 
  height: 6.8em;
  border-radius: 1em/.5em;
  background: #ccc;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 3em;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.hex:before, .hex:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit; height: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
}
.hex:before {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.hex:after {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
.hex:hover {
  background: #F58787;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hexMidden:hover {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ol class="even">
            <li class='hex'></li>
            <li class='hex'></li>
        </ol>  
        <ol class="odd">
            <li class='hex'></li>
            <li class='hex' id="hexMidden"></li>
            <li class='hex'></li>
        </ol>
        <ol class="even">
            <li class='hex'></li>
            <li class='hex'></li>
        </ol>  
    </div>
</body>
```

The code above I found on the Internet.

Comment: When you say "on top" can you be a little more clear?

Comment: You can make p tags or spans or whatever somewhere and use position absolute on them and z-index. The give left and top values to position them on the screen where you want them. That is if this doesn't need to be responsive.

Comment: @im1dermike : The hexagon has a background-color and I want some numbers on top of that.. So that the numbers are in the hexagon.

Comment: @floor : Thanks, but first I want to try if there's another way so that I can make it responsible.

Comment: Why not add the text to the `li` tags? Using `text-align:center` and a line height that matches the height of the `.hex`

Comment: @Jrod It warps the hexagon shape, the way its being done any text being or elements that take up space to the li will wrap it all.

Comment: @Jrod : When I add it to the li tags my hexagon doens't look like a hexagon anymore..

Comment: @Lotte you can still make it responsive kind of with the approach I gave only you would have to use media queries and control where the text is based on some set screen sizes.

Comment: Another option may be to not force the css to make hexagons and instead use images for them. That option would make your life a lot easier haha.

Answer (score 2):

```
.hex-text {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index: 999;
  left: 5px;
  top: 30px;
}

<li class='hex'>
    <div class="hex-text">Words words words</div>
</li>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/zsmvxbbw/)**

```css
   .container {
  width: 1000px; 
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-left: 30%;
}
ol.even {
  position: relative;
  left: 3.63em;
}
ol.odd {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -6.5%;
  margin-bottom: -6.5%;
}
.hex {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 4em; 
  height: 6.8em;
  border-radius: 1em/.5em;
  background: #ccc;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 3em;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.hex:before, .hex:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit; height: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
}
.hex:before {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.hex:after {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
.hex:hover {
  background: #F58787;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hexMidden:hover {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: auto;
}
.hex-text {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index: 999;
  left: 5px;
  top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ol class="even">
            <li class='hex'><div class="hex-text">Words words words</div></li>
            <li class='hex'><div class="hex-text">Words words words</div></li>
        </ol>  
        <ol class="odd">
            <li class='hex'><div class="hex-text">Words words words</div></li>
            <li class='hex'><div class="hex-text">Words words words</div></li>
            <li class='hex'><div class="hex-text">Words words words</div></li>
        </ol>
        <ol class="even">
            <li class='hex'><div class="hex-text">Words words words</div></li>
            <li class='hex'><div class="hex-text">Words words words</div></li>
        </ol>  
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit convoluted, but because you have designated a height for your hexagons, it is possible to do this with a few spans:

```
.hex > span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 6.8em;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 20;
}
    .hex > span > span {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height: 1em; 
    }
```

What this is essentially doing is creating a text area the same height as your hexagon and undoing the rotation, causing the text to appear correctly.  The `z-index` throws it above the rest of the Hexagon and the `text-align: center` puts the text neatly in the middle of whatever hex it's added to.  Sadly, the two spans are necessary to ensure more than one line of text won't break the effect.

You say you want numbers, however, so it might be possible to do this with one span per text by adding a `white-space: nowrap` to the first child span, I'll make a separate Fiddle for that version.

[Fiddle for multi-line text](http://jsfiddle.net/Oceanity/z92oh0d7/)

[Fiddle for single-line numbers](http://jsfiddle.net/Oceanity/mkhd8nha/3/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Or simply add to your CSS:

```css
.number {
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: -85px;
}
```

And change your HTML to:

```
<div class="container">
    <ol class="even">
        <li class='hex'></li><span class="number">1</span>
        <li class='hex'></li><span class="number">2</span>
    </ol>  
    <ol class="odd">
        <li class='hex'></li><span class="number">3</span>
        <li class='hex' id="hexMidden"></li><span class="number">4</span>
        <li class='hex'></li><span class="number">5</span>
    </ol>
    <ol class="even">
        <li class='hex'></li><span class="number">6</span>
        <li class='hex'></li><span class="number">7</span>
    </ol>  
</div>
```

Working DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/3t4680ve/

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px; 
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-left: 30%;
}
ol.even {
  position: relative;
  left: 3.63em;
}
ol.odd {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -6.5%;
  margin-bottom: -6.5%;
}
.hex {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 4em; 
  height: 6.8em;
  border-radius: 1em/.5em;
  background: #ccc;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 3em;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.hex:before, .hex:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit; height: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
}
.hex:before {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.hex:after {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
.hex:hover {
  background: #F58787;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#hexMidden:hover {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: auto;
}
.number {
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: -85px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ol class="even">
        <li class='hex'></li><span class="number">1</span>
        <li class='hex'></li><span class="number">2</span>
    </ol>  
    <ol class="odd">
        <li class='hex'></li><span class="number">3</span>
        <li class='hex' id="hexMidden"></li><span class="number">4</span>
        <li class='hex'></li><span class="number">5</span>
    </ol>
    <ol class="even">
        <li class='hex'></li><span class="number">6</span>
        <li class='hex'></li><span class="number">7</span>
    </ol>  
</div>
```

Comment: Looks nice but, at least on my phone, the hexagons can be scrolled away from the numbers.